# Change cursor drag color of android webview input box

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, webview, android-webview

I am developing a cordova application. In my application i am using HTML input box.
On android kitkat (nexus 5) when i am selecting some text in input field than cursor drag is coming in white color.
The background color of screen is also white so it is not visible and it seems UI is distorted.
On other android device it is coming in some different colors so looking good.

So is there any way to set some custom color for this cursor drag?

screenshot attached[image] for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can change color by providing appropriate [theme](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html). Attribute color accent changes not only this pin color but also other main effects in your layout.

However if you want to change only this color of the element in this control - try to instantiate your web view with `ContextThemeWrapper` that will reference separate theme with appropriate color.